# Pythagorean question for vector calculation

Tags: geometry

[image]

The only quantities I know are d and e, but b = c. The left and bottom sides are perpendicular (this is a right triangle). Is it possible to find a and b? Its a vector diagram of a problem I already asked a question for ([Formula to find unknown C and Rl in RC filter](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2934926/formula-to-find-unknown-c-and-rl-in-rc-filter)), but had no answers, but now I have removed the electronics aspect to the original question I hope someone might be able to help.

The use I have for this is as follows. I have an unknown capacitor and resistor in parallel, and I can drive them at 2 frequencies and measure their lumped impedance. So that is d and e in the above diagram. Side a is the resistance and side b is the capacitance. There is a diagram of the system in the other post I made on this site a few days ago. I solved it for pure resistance on my own but when it came to making one element capacitive I failed.

Where is this useful to me? The capacitor is a lossy capacitor with both capacitance and resistance in parallel (a slightly conductive water based dielectric). The only way to measure its capacitance without measuring phase is as I have described above, and due to the small capacitance and relatively large resistance it has measuring phase at the frequencies required is tricky with a mcu which is my aim. However measuring amplitude is easy and driving it with more than one frequency is easy so this is my current approach, will see if it works in the real world next though.

Edit: Figured out the working with the help of seeing what the right result was:
I had this bit
$d^2 = a^2 + b^2$  and   $e^2 = a^2 + (2b)^2$

$a^2 = d^2-b^2$

$a^2 = e^2-(2b)^2$

But had done this bit wrong...
$d^2-b^2 = e^2-4b^2$

$d^2 = e^2-4b^2 + b^2$

$d^2 = e^2 - 3b^2$

$3b^2 = e^2 - d^2$

$b^2 = {\Large e^2 - d^2 \over \Large 3}$

$b = \sqrt{\Large e^2 - d^2 \over \Large 3}$


$b^2 = d^2-a^2$

$4b^2 = e^2-a^2$

$4d^2-4a^2 = e^2-a^2$

$4d^2-e^2 = 4a^2-a^2$

$3a^2 = 4d^2-e^2$

$a^2 = {\Large 4d^2-e^2 \over \Large 3}$

$a = \sqrt{\Large 4d^2-e^2 \over \Large 3}$


Rusty cogs in the brain eventually loosened with the help of being able to see the answer so thanks again!

Comment: The image seems to indicate that the left side and the bottom side are perpendicular. If this is so, it should be mentioned in the question (or shown in the image with the usual square in the corner).

Comment: apologies for that - I knocked the image together late last night on a borrowed computer and didn't know how to use the package. Image is generally poor, looking at other images on here they are very nicely drawn, so once again sorry.

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Comment: Context - might be too late now but here goes for interest. I have an unknown capacitor and resistor in parallel, and I can drive them at 2 frequencies and measure their lumped impedance. So that is d and e in the above diagram. Side a is the resistance and side b is the capacitance. There is a diagram of the system in the other post I made on this site a few days ago. I solved it for pure resistance on my own but when it came to making one element capacitive I failed. Its not homework (far too old - I wish it was!), its for a sensor I am working on with unknown R and C elements.

Comment: So the context is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2934926/formula-to-find-unknown-c-and-rl-in-rc-filter, right? You could have improved the other question by editing it and adding what you had found out about the problem (including the fact that you could solve it with the figure above, with the explanation of what that figure had to do with the circuit). That also would have been a clue that the figure was a right triangle (because some of us know that capacitive impedance is orthogonal to resistive impedance).

Comment: I think that is great as for context. It's fine (preferable actually) to add that to your question. Often, people who downvote or vote-to-close don't read comments; furthermore, comments can be deleted.

Comment: Have added context and a bit of other background to the question, and I will link the original question to this one too so as to provide a solution. Thanks for the comments in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Pythagore's theorem. You get :

$$a^2 + b^2 = d^2 \quad \text{and} \quad a^2 + (2b)^2 = e^2$$

Solving this system, you get
$$a = \sqrt{\frac{4d^2-e^2}{3}} \quad \text{and}\quad  b= \sqrt{\frac{e^2-d^2}{3}}$$

Comment: Blooming brilliant thanks! I got as far as 4d^2 - e^2 but then I tried to root that and didn't divide by 3 first. Spent several hours trying to figure out what was wrong. How did you solve that system, and where can I read up on the technique more? Where did the divide by 3 come from? I probably knew 30 years ago, it feels familiar, but its gone at the moment.

Comment: Pete, just multiply the first equation of @TheSilverDoe by 4 and subtract the second one. The effect of that is that this eliminates the variable b and explanates too where that 3 derives from.